# When writing data using Python-docx, how do I get text and images on the same line?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I have been using Python-doc to operate Word recently, and now I want to write a piece of data, which contains text and images. I need to make the text and images on the same line, but I have tried many methods, and all of them can only be a line of text and a line of images. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_paragraph('111111111111')
document.add_picture(r'G:\141-220F411194A92.png', width=Inches(1.25))

document.save(r'G:\\1.docx')
```

Comment: Related: [add two images in same line in python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57363257/15740324)

Answer (score 0):

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph('')
r = p.add_run('111111111111')
r.add_picture(r'G:\141-220F411194A92.png', width=Inches(1.25))

document.save(r'G:\\1.docx')
```